# Show/Hide Columns in Boot grid when onclick - Externally

Tags: jquery-bootgrid

i couldn't hide a show/hide a boot grid column after onclick boot grid re-load.
The issue is it works when the page is loaded first time, but i couldn't make it work after click event. Any help is appreciated.

```
<th id="th_state" data-identifier="true"  data-column-id="state" data-visible="false">State</th>         

 $('#filter_group').change(function () {     
    $("#employee_grid").bootgrid("reload") 
    $("#th_state").attr("data-visible", "true")  ;    // Not working....
 });                   

$("#employee_grid").bootgrid({
                    ajax: true,
                    rowCount: [50, 100, 200, 300, 500],

                    columnSelection: true,
                    requestHandler: function (request) {
                        request.type = 'grid';
                        var citiesGroup = [];
                                               $("#cities_group").find("option:selected").each(function (index, value) {
                            if ($(this).is(':selected')) {
                                citiesGroup.push({
                                    state: $(this).parent().attr("label"),
                                    city: $(this).val()
                                });
                            }
                        });

                        if (request.sort) {
                            request.sortBy = Object.keys(request.sort)[0]; 
                           request.sortOrder = request.sort[request.sortBy];
                            request.chartType = $("#chartType").val();
                            request.date_from = $("#date_from").val();
                            request.date_to = $("#date_to").val();
                            request.citiesGroup = citiesGroup ;
                            delete request.sort
                        }
                        return request;
                    },
                    responseHandler: function (response) {
                        $("#txt_total_connects").html(response);


                        return response;

                    },
                    post: function ()
                    {
                        /* To accumulate custom parameter with the request object */
                        return {
                            id: "b0df282a-0d67-40e5-8558-c9e93b7befed"
                        };
                    },
                    url: "response.php",
                    formatters: {
                    },
                    labels: {
                        noResults: "<b>No data found</b>",
                        all: "",
                        loading: '<b>Loading Please wait....</b>'
                    },
                    templates: {
                        search: "",
                        //header: "",
                    }                    
                });
```

Comment: Hi All, any replies for this???

Comment: Can you make this code in fiddle?